# Jquery Automatic Input Field Data Formatting

Tags: jquery, input, formatting, field

This is how i want the automatic formatting to work in a input field!

(01) some text

So i want the user only be able to write two numbers and those numbers gets a "(" before the number, and this behind the number ")" and then the user can write some text.

I been looking at some Jquery formats but as im not really good at Jquery its not leading me in the right direction :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Automatic-Input-Field-Data-Formatting-Plugin-jQuery-mask.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: check [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask
This is pretty much all the code you need

```
$('#maskedText').inputmask("(99)a{*}");
```

Here is the fiddle with a working a example of what you want https://jsfiddle.net/2mLxkzw9/595/

Comment: jsfiddle is not working from here right now.. But YES thats what i was looking FOR!.. thanks!

Comment: Love it!.. but that code dont allow space in the text.. or i haven't figure out how to allow it!.. yet

Comment: Ok i was guessing it was a more easy way that i missed.. But that works amazing.